# select orders where product name like

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables:

1. `Orders`: (`orderId`, `customerId`, `date`, etc)
2. `Order_products`: (`orderProductId`, `orderId`, `productId`, `quantity`)
3. `Products`: (`productId`, `productName`, etc)

How would I be able to select orders that have products with

```
productName LIKE 'pattern'
```

I am using codeigniter's query builder, so an answer using it would be appreciated however raw SQL is fine also.

Comment: Please share the code what you tried so far ....

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and be clear about your version, because pattern matching has improved

Comment: @Strawberry i'll keep this in mind next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query to get what you want

```
SELECT tb1.orderId
FROM Orders tb1
LEFT JOIN Order_products tb2 ON tb2.orderId = tb1.orderId
LEFT JOIN Products tb3 ON tb3.productId = tb2.productId
WHERE tb3.productName LIKE '%pattern%'
```

NOTE: Better to user '%pattern%' like this (% in both side of the key), Avoid to use * in select query

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN tb3... WHERE tb3.productName LIKE '%pattern%'` is the same as `INNER JOIN tb3`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work I guess (don't know for code igniter)

```
SELECT orderId FROM Order_products WHERE productId IN 
(SELECT productId FROM Products WHERE productName LIKE '%pattern%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('O.*')
->from('Orders as O')
->join('Order_products as OP','OP.orderId = O.orderId')
->join('Products as P','P.productId = OP.productId')
->like("P.productName","PATTERN");

$query = $this->db->get();
$query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Products');
$this->db->join('Order_products', 'Order_products.productId=Products.productId');
$this->db->join('Orders', 'Orders.orderId=Order_products.orderId');
$this->db->where("Products.productName LIKE '%$keyword%'");
$query = $this->db->get();
$query->result_array();
```

Comment: I upvote you for increase your reputation then upvote me 10 questions